# There is no argument given that corresponds to the required formal parameter 'id' of 'Human.Human(int, string, string, string)'

Tags: c#, .net

I cannot call new Human object from Homecontrollers action method.

```
        var employee = new Human { id = 1, name = "home index" , isAuth = isAuth,token="null"};
```

this is my model

```
namespace WebApplication3.Models
{
    public class Human
    {
        public Human(int id, string name, string isAuth, string token)
        {
            this.id = id;
            this.name = name;
            this.isAuth = isAuth;
            this.token = token;
        }
```

Comment: It should be like new Human( id = 1, name = "home index" , isAuth = isAuth,token="null"); Instead of curly braces use round one for constructor.

Comment: Or add an empty constructor (provided that those properties are public)

Comment: @Gaurav, you can't use '=' to name parameters. Either `var employee = new Human (id: 1, name: "home index", isAuth: isAuth, token: "null");` or  just `var employee = new Human (1, "home index", isAuth, "null");`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are using the syntax for [Object Initializer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/how-to-initialize-objects-by-using-an-object-initializer) but this syntax requires at least an empty constructor to be used because the code inside the curly braces is executed after the object is constructed.

If you want to use that syntax you need an emtpy constructor to be added to your model

```
public class Human
{
    public Human() {}

    public Human(int id, string name, string isAuth, string token)
    {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.isAuth = isAuth;
        this.token = token;
    }
```

Now you have two choices. Use the current syntax so the compiler calls the empty constructor and then initializes the properties with the values between curly braces or just call directly the constructor with the four parameters using the normal syntax.

```
var employee = new Human (1,"home index",isAuth,"null");
```

Note that for the first approach you need those properties to be public

```
public class Human
{
    public int id {get;set;}           
    .....
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
var employee = new Human(1, "home index" isAuth, null);
```

Comment: Or `var employee = new Human(id: 1, name: "home index", isAuth: isAuth, token: null);` with colons if it helps with the readability.